# Sponsored Tags and Tag Synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process, sponsored-tags

I wasn't sure whether to post this question on MSO or MSE, but since it deals with SO tags, I decided on MSO.

I have a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184502/synonyms-requests-of-android-gcm) in MSE asking to make the tags [google-cloud-messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging) and [gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcm) synonyms of [android-gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gcm). All three tags refer mostly to the same thing - Google Cloud Messaging for Android applications (with the exception of a few questions under the [google-cloud-messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging) tag that refer to Google Cloud Messaging for Chrome - I created a new tag [chrome-gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrome-gcm) for those questions).

The [suggested synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-gcm/synonyms) for [android-gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gcm) already contain [google-cloud-messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging) and [gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcm), but they are lacking votes in order to automatically become synonyms.

However, recently I discovered [google-cloud-messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging) became a sponsored tag, which is funny, since that's the least popular of those 3 equivalent tags (it has 4 times less questions than [android-gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gcm) and 3 times less questions than [gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcm)).

Does the fact that it's sponsored protect it from becoming a synonym of [android-gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gcm)? What would happen if people vote to make it a synonym? Would [android-gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gcm) become the sponsored tag?

If the sponsor (which I assume is Google) prefers to sponsor [google-cloud-messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging), should this become the "main" GCM tag, and the other two become synonyms of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nobody answered this question, so I might as well do it myself.

> If the sponsor (which I assume is Google) prefers to sponsor [google-cloud-messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging), should this become the "main" GCM tag, and the other two become synonyms of it?

Aparantly, the answer to that is yes. [google-cloud-messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging) became the main GCM tag, and [gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcm) and [android-gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gcm) became synonyms of it.

[Here's the question that finally got this issue resolved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281709/double-tags-for-google-cloud-messaging-lets-merge-these-suckers/).