# Double tags for Google Cloud Messaging? Let's merge these suckers!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request, synonym-request

So, the excerpt for [google-cloud-messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging) starts out "Google Cloud Messaging is a service to allow data to be sent remotely to Android applications." Good stuff! It's sponsored. Got 540+ questions and 30-some followers. Etc.

Unfortunately, a very similar phrase is used for [android-gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gcm), which has almost 3k questions (that aren't also tagged [google-cloud-messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging)) and 150+ followers! This is far from ideal, since, for all the world, these appear to be exactly the same technology, an impression that is only strengthened by the fact that [android-gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gcm) has [gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcm) synonymized to it (since originally posting this) and a suggestion for synonymizing [google-cloud-messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging) to it as well.

But that seems a little backward, since it's ignoring the sponsored status. Instead, it seems like [android-gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gcm) should probably be synonymized to its sponsored counterpart to bring all the questions under the official roof. The situation was partially recognized in [Merge GCM and google-cloud-messaging tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254289/4099598), but only two of the three involved tags were noticed, and the proposal seems to be a recycled question that didn't get much attention at the time and has not been updated since then. And in [Sponsored Tags and Tag Synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255806/4099598), the assumption was that a (now closed as off-topic) MSE question would handle the actual merging that the question was considering in the general case.

Comment: Nobody is (was) commenting or answering, just upvoting. That says enough ;-)

Comment: They're same technology and most of the questions are similar. But there's already a request here - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254289/merge-gcm-and-google-cloud-messaging-tag?lq=1

Comment: @noob: Yes, I noted that specifically in my post and explained why the previous request was inadequate. So while one of these posts is arguably a dupe of the other… I'm not at all sure it's this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcm) and [android-gcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gcm) -> [google-cloud-messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging) - merged and syn'd.